# Eclipse - import java.io.FileOuputStream; not working

Tags: java, eclipse, serialization, import, fileoutputstream

I am doing a computer science project using serialization and I have run into problems with importing "java.io.FileOuputStream" in eclipse.

When I hover over the error, it says that 'this import cannot be resolved'.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You should provide more information.... You have problem only with this import or with another jdk classes? Please attach source code and screen from IDE

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.